# Remove google maps background-color

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, background-color

I am trying to make my google maps transparent. I have managed to changed the opacity of the map tiles (markers are also transparent but I need to sort that out later).I wanted to add a gradient to the  that would look like folds in the page and then have the transparent maps overlaying it so it looks fold lines in a map.

I noticed that google is adding a background color to the div containing the maps... a slight obstical in my plan.

I tried targeting the div with jquery to set the background to none. Unfortunatly for me Google won and I couldn't change it.

```
$('div div#example').css("background-color","#000");
```

Here is a fiddle showing how I have things set up http://jsfiddle.net/pTuQ4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [map option](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions) to change the background color: `backgroundColor`

For example:

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    backgroundColor: "black"
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much that is exactly what I was looking for worked like a charm even with gmap3. thanks for the help! Here is the version with background color set to none http://jsfiddle.net/daimz/pTuQ4/4/