# How to style the "unloaded map" portion of Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to style my Google Map in dark mode using the API.

I found [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/style-array) and it works fine.  But the problem is, if I scroll the map quickly, the portions of the map that have not loaded yet are a light gray color, completely defeating the purpose of dark mode to not put out much light.

My first assumption was that I just need to add an "elementType" corresponding to unloaded tiles.  But then I found [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference) which doesn't help, although it says I can select "all" features.  But when I do this it doesn't affect the color of unloaded map tiles.

How can I make Google Maps change the unloaded tile color?

Comment: Duplicate of [Remove google maps background-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201259/remove-google-maps-background-color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  believe you are looking for the [MapOption](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions): [backgroundColor](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.backgroundColor):

> **backgroundColor** *optional*
> Type:  string *optional*
> Color used for the background of the Map div. This color will be visible when tiles have not yet loaded as the user pans. This option can only be set when the map is initialized.

Something like:

```
backgroundColor: "black",
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/xvnmue5h/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map, zoomed out to show background]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  // Styles a map in night mode.
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: {
      lat: 40.674,
      lng: -73.945
    },
    zoom: 0,
    backgroundColor: "black",
    styles: [{
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [{
          color: "#242f3e"
        }]
      },
      {
        elementType: "labels.text.stroke",
        stylers: [{
          color: "#242f3e"
        }]
      },
      {
        elementType: "labels.text.fill",
        stylers: [{
          color: "#746855"
        }]
      },
      {
        featureType: "administrative.locality",
        elementType: "labels.text.fill",
        stylers: [{
          color: "#d59563"
        }],
      },
      {
        featureType: "poi",
        elementType: "labels.text.fill",
        stylers: [{
          color: "#d59563"
        }],
      },
      {
        featureType: "poi.park",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [{
          color: "#263c3f"
        }],
      },
      {
        featureType: "poi.park",
        elementType: "labels.text.fill",
        stylers: [{
          color: "#6b9a76"
        }],
      },
      {
        featureType: "road",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [{
          color: "#38414e"
        }],
      },
      {
        featureType: "road",
        elementType: "geometry.stroke",
        stylers: [{
          color: "#212a37"
        }],
      },
      {
        featureType: "road",
        elementType: "labels.text.fill",
        stylers: [{
          color: "#9ca5b3"
        }],
      },
      {
        featureType: "road.highway",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [{
          color: "#746855"
        }],
      },
      {
        featureType: "road.highway",
        elementType: "geometry.stroke",
        stylers: [{
          color: "#1f2835"
        }],
      },
      {
        featureType: "road.highway",
        elementType: "labels.text.fill",
        stylers: [{
          color: "#f3d19c"
        }],
      },
      {
        featureType: "transit",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [{
          color: "#2f3948"
        }],
      },
      {
        featureType: "transit.station",
        elementType: "labels.text.fill",
        stylers: [{
          color: "#d59563"
        }],
      },
      {
        featureType: "water",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [{
          color: "#17263c"
        }],
      },
      {
        featureType: "water",
        elementType: "labels.text.fill",
        stylers: [{
          color: "#515c6d"
        }],
      },
      {
        featureType: "water",
        elementType: "labels.text.stroke",
        stylers: [{
          color: "#17263c"
        }],
      },
    ],
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Styled Maps - Night Mode</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```